# VM gets an APIPA after Reboot

Tags: ip, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2, vsphere, vcenter

after rebooting a VM I get sometimes (~3 reboots - 1 apipa) an APIPA-IP Adress although I set a static IP.

Resetting the interface (OS) or reconnect the network adapter (VM) is fixing the problem.

[image]

```
System Informations:

vCenter 5.5 + ESX 5.5

VMTools 9.4.10 build 2092844 - 2008R2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**: Disable and Enable the `NIC` - most of the times this should solve the issue.

**Solution 2** : Create the following registry key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
```

Do a reboot.

**Solution 3** : remove the `NIC`, reboot the `vm` and add the `NIC` back.